# Javascript: calling function within D3 from another file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, import, include

I want to rewrite several functions, relating to one of the layouts, in the d3.js script. When I cut-and-paste these functions into separate files and load them after d3.js, visualizations no longer work, because internal functions call internal functions of d3.js.

d3.js:

```
!function() {
  var d3 = { version: "3.5.17" };
  function d3_funct() { return d3; } // this function is called in the other file
}();
```

chord.js:

```
d3.svg.chord() = function() {
  var funct = d3_funct; // doesn't work
};
```

**Question:**

How would I use the above function, `d3_funct`, inside my script chord.js, when `d3_funct` is defined inside an immediately-executed function expression in another file?

Options:

1. edit d3.js file directly instead of pulling out functions to rewrite :(
2. Rename the enclosing d3 function and use jQuery to load it into chord.js.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your order of execution should be:

1. Load d3.js
2. Load your custom modifications
3. Load the rest of your code

Your modifications file should look something like:

```
function myBetterD3Funct () { ... }
d3.d3_funct = myBetterD3Funct;
```

The above would be by far the best option. It's extremely clear what you're doing and doesn't require you to modify the d3.js file every time you download the newest version (thus allowing you to use a d3 cdn to serve d3.js to your users).

Another option exists if you don't want to override the d3 global function itself. I warn you that the below may not work for all cases depending on how complex your `myBetterD3Funct` and what it needs access to within `d3`.

```
function myBetterD3Funct () { ... }
myBetterD3Funct.apply(d3);
```

What this is doing is setting the scope of your function (at runtime) to the global d3 object. This would allow it to reference top-level properties within the global `d3` object using `this`. As noted in a comment below, many functions and variables within the code are [written to be private](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), and so you cannot access them in any way (save for modifying the source code).

Comment: "This would allow it to reference anything within the global `d3` object using `this`." - not everything: in fact, you can't access local variables (which is what OP is trying to access). OP, the d3 code is deliberately written in this way so you can't access it: it is the JavaScript private value pattern.

Comment: D3 v4.0 has been broken into "modules". Do you think that this may suit the OP better?

Comment: @Amadan he should be able to access local variables at the top level (those directly on the `d3` object). But yeah, there is no way to get inside closed functions - I'll clear that up with an update.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it may or may not. I'm not familiar with the new structure, but it would depend on how it is organized and what exactly the OP needs access to.

Comment: "those directly on the `d3` level" - those are not local variables. `d3.foo` is a property, and accessible from outside. `var foo` (or `function foo()`) is a local variable, and inaccessible from outside. It does not matter what your context is - your trick just means you can access `d3.foo` as `this.foo`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd need access to local variables. Both options still break on ReferenceError. I didn't realize that so much of d3 is deliberately set private, but that makes sense -- I think your answer would have worked with other scripts.